# Dynamically manipulate element attributes using input controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom, element

I would like to use the input controls to manipulate elements dynamically. Either Pure JavaScript or jQuery is fine.

```
 src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" >
</br><br>
<form class="button" action="">
Width
<input class="button" type="number" value="300">
Height  
<input class="button" type="number" value="400">
 </form>
```

The result would be something like this:

[image: Example result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add some `id` attributes, get a reference to your elements in JavaScript and update the image style `oninput` (when the value of the width or height is changed)

```js
let img = document.getElementById('img');
let width = document.getElementById('width');
let height = document.getElementById('height');

changeSize = () => {
  img.style.width = `${width.value}px`;
  img.style.height = `${height.value}px`;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/rock600x400.jpg" />
</br><br>
<form class="button" action="">
  Width
  <input id="width" class="button" type="number" value="300" oninput="changeSize()"> Height
  <input id="height" class="button" type="number" value="400" oninput="changeSize()">
</form>
```